# How can have Indeterminate CheckBox changed to Checked instead of Unchecked?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `CheckBox` that is set to `CheckState.Indeterminate`.  When a timer expires it will be set to `CheckState.Unchecked` and turn off an external output signal. So far so good.

With the current code when the user clicks on the `Indeterminate CheckBox` it will become an `Unchecked CheckBox`.  I would like to intercept it and make it a `Checked CheckBox`.

The effect for the user would be to cancel the timer and leave the output on until the user unchecks the box or the user starts a separate process that takes over and the Indeterminate CheckBox` is set again.

As it is he turns off the output and has to explicitly turn it on again.

I tried the validating event, but that doesn't happen until I leave the box.

**Update 1:** To clarify a little bit what the user wants to see.
When the lights are off the box is always unchecked.

When the automated part of the system is running, the light is on. If the user looks at the control it is in the indeterminate state because the user did not activate it it, but it is on.

When the process stops a timer is started leaving the lights on for 2 minutes. The user still sees the indeterminate state during this time.

If the user needs the light to remain on he will check the box removing the indeterminate state. When he is through he will manually uncheck the box turning off the light or restart the automated process which will make it indeterminate again.

I wasn't aware of the **AutoCheck** property

Comment: I don't know if I get it right. You say when the user clicks the checkbox you want to omit the Unchecked state and set it as checked. Is that correct?

Comment: @KarelTamayo Yes.

Comment: Did you try `CheckState_Changed` event?

Comment: The problem  I had was it is already changed when I see that event. So I don't know if it was intermediate or checked before.  I see the AutoCheck property will change that behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for anything drastic, you just don't like the way that Checkbox implemented its AutoCheck property.  So select the control and set its AutoCheck property to False.  That let's you control the check state the way you want it.

Add the Click event handler to allow the user to flip the state straight from Indeterminate to Checked with a mouse click or spacebar press:

```
    private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        checkBox1.CheckState = checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked ?
            CheckState.Unchecked : CheckState.Checked;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm advising against changing the behavior of standard controls, but if this is what you need, you can subclass the CheckBox and override the Onclick method.

[This](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/CheckBox.cs,dcda8bb30747f876,references) is where you can see what the standard behavior is.

All you need to do is rework that logic in the switch statement and call the base. We need to suppress the base's checkstate logic by setting AutoCheck to false, then restore it to its previous value afterwards:

```
public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AutoCheck)
            switch (CheckState)
            {
                case CheckState.Indeterminate:
                    CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                    break;
                case CheckState.Unchecked:
                    if (ThreeState)
                    {
                        CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
                    break;
            }

        var oldAutoCheckValue = AutoCheck;
        AutoCheck = false;
        base.OnClick(e);
        AutoCheck = oldAutoCheckValue;
    }
}
```

As an alternative solution, you should consider using radio buttons to improve UX.

Comment: The radio button cannot be "Unchecked" and would not easily reflect a simple "light switch" to the user.  I updated the answer to reflect the working logic and added a description of its purpose since it isn't very obvious.

Comment: How would a three state checkbox reflect a simple "light switch" to the user in the indeterminate state?

Comment: I don't like how the edited answer works. It's hard to follow how the logic plays out, especially with the comments that are contradicting what is being done.

Comment: A good solution is to turn off AutoCheck, to suppress the base's check state logic and then restore it to its previous value.

Comment: Your updated answer does work and is clearer than my edit was. But I agree that using the `AutoCheck = false` property to allow me to manually set the state makes the most sense and is much simpler to maintain than a new component. I learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `CheckStateChanged` event.

Try this and let me know:

```
//mark the process as running (check box is Indeterminate state)
private bool processIsRunning = true;

private void chkState_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //the user clicks the indeterminate checkbox
    if (processIsRunning && chkState.CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked)
    {
        processIsRunning = false;
        chkState.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was close and I probably could make it work, but I think it would call itself when it overrode the current state. So I would need more state variables to ignore the secondary change.