# When clicking in rapid succession, the inappropriate answer goes to the selection box. Why? What is the right way?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Please add a CheckBox and a CheckedListBox to the form
I have a check box list, when I click on an item quickly, the check box (select all) gets an inappropriate response.
_vb.net vs2019

```
    Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For a = 0 To 8
            CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("a" & a)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedValueChanged
        Dim chkState As CheckState
        If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count = 0 Then
            chkState = CheckState.Unchecked
        ElseIf CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count = CheckedListBox1.Items.Count Then
            chkState = CheckState.Checked
        Else
            chkState = CheckState.Indeterminate
        End If
        CheckBox1.CheckState = chkState
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [ItemCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck) event but you will have to factor in the [NewState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.itemcheckeventargs.newvalue) property of the [ItemCheckEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.itemcheckeventargs) object it gives you.  `CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count` is not yet updated at the time of this event:

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    Dim chkState As CheckState

    Dim checkedItems As Integer = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count
    If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then checkedItems += 1
    If e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked Then checkedItems -= 1

    Select Case checkedItems
        Case 0
            chkState = CheckState.Unchecked
        Case CheckedListBox1.Items.Count
            chkState = CheckState.Checked
        Case Else
            chkState = CheckState.Indeterminate
    End Select

    CheckBox1.CheckState = chkState

End Sub
```

Comment: If possible, give another answer.
When the checkbox(Select All) is in Indeterminate mode, click on it first to check it.then uncheck it

Comment: @MansourDalir see [How can have Indeterminate CheckBox changed to Checked instead of Unchecked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323634/how-can-have-indeterminate-checkbox-changed-to-checked-instead-of-unchecked)

Comment: How is it used in vb language? The solution language was not in the vb link.